# Read buffer while data is being loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

There is a big media file I would would like to play on Chrome using `webkit sound API` (The file I get using `XMLHTTPRequest` or `$.GET`).

I can see in the browser's Developer Tools that the data is being downloaded into some buffer, but have to wait until process is done. Is there a way to get an access to the buffer and read data already loaded and not waiting for the end of process?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about accessing the downloaded data, but you can use a streaming source. [More info here.](http://ianreah.com/2013/02/28/Real-time-analysis-of-streaming-audio-data-with-Web-Audio-API.html#a_streaming_sound_source)